# Selecting rows based on condition in R and keep rows with missing values

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R (dd_sub) with a column (E) and want to drop the rows where E > 0.
The column has rows where E = "NA" , E < 0 and E > 0.

When I write this:

```
dd_subset <- dd_sub[ which( dd_sub$E < 0 | dd_sub$E == "NA"), ]
```

I only get the row where E < 0.

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `which()`. You can just declare the condition - which returns a logical array - so the rows whose position is TRUE in the condition are selected.

Also, `dd_sub$E == "NA"` match a string 'NA', not the definition of missing value. `is.na()` returns TRUE in the positions where the value is missing.

```
dd_subset <- dd_sub[dd_sub$E < 0 | is.na(dd_sub$E), ]
```

Other possibility is to write the negative - with `!` - of the rows you want to drop.

```
dd_subset <- dd_sub[! dd_sub$E >= 0]
```